# Variable Not In Scope of Match in Rust

Tags: rust

I implementing the following drag and drop function with [fltk-rs](https://github.com/MoAlyousef/fltk-rs):

```rust
fn handleImageDrag(t:&mut Button, e:Event)->bool{
    let mut dnd = false;
    let mut released = false;

    match e {
        Event::DndEnter => {
            dnd = true;
            println!("{}", "did enter!");
            println!("dnd value at DndEnter is: {}", dnd);
            true
        }
        Event::DndDrag => true,
        Event::DndRelease => {
            released = true;
            println!("released value at DndRelease is: {}", released);
            true
        }
        Event::Paste => {
            println!("{}", "did paste!");
            println!("dnd value at Paste is: {}", dnd);
            println!("released value at Paste is: {}", released);
            // println!("{}", released);
            if dnd && released {
                let img = image::open("imgs/3.jpg").unwrap();
                let thumbnail = img.resize(400,400, FilterType::Lanczos3);
                let (x, y) = thumbnail.dimensions();
                let rgb = RgbImage::new(&thumbnail.to_bytes(), x, y, 3).unwrap();
                t.set_image(Some(rgb));
                dnd = false;
                released = false;
                true
            } else {
                false
            }
        }
        Event::DndLeave => {
            dnd = false;
            released = false;
            true
        }
        _ => false,
    }
}
```

```rust
testBut2.handle2(move |t, ev| {handleImageDrag(t,ev)});
//dragging and dropping then prints:
did enter!
dnd value at DndEnter is: true
released value at DndRelease is: true
did paste!
dnd value at Paste is: false
released value at Paste is: false
```

I've initialized dnd and released as mutable booleans, so I thought that I could change their value in the match{} portion of the function. The values of dnd and released are changed in DnDEnter and DndRelease respectively, but when I access those values in Paste they are not the updated values. Are the variables some how out of scope?

Comment: You are declaring the variables inside the function, so the values only exist for one function call. They are not modified between function calls, it will always be `false` when it is `Event::Paste`.

Comment: @Deadbeef  so how would I preserve the value between these function calls while declaring the varibles inside the function?

Comment: There are no (safe) mutable global variables in rust without declaring it as a `Mutex`. If you are passing the function pointer to another, consider using a closure, so you can mutate the captured value between calls.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```rust
let mut dnd = false;
let mut released = false;

imgSlot1.handle2(move |t, ev| {handleImageDrag(t,ev, &mut dnd, &mut released)});

fn handleImageDrag(t:&mut Button, e:Event, dnd:&mut bool, released: &mut bool)->bool{
    // let mut dnd = false;
    // let mut released = false;

    match e {
        Event::DndEnter => {
            *dnd = true;
            println!("{}", "did enter!");
            println!("dnd value at DndEnter is: {}", dnd);
            true
        }
        Event::DndDrag => true,
        Event::DndRelease => {
            *released = true;
            println!("released value at DndRelease is: {}", released);
            true
        }
        Event::Paste => {
            println!("{}", "did paste!");
            println!("dnd value at Paste is: {}", dnd);
            println!("released value at Paste is: {}", released);
            // println!("{}", released);
            if *dnd && *released {
                let img = image::open("imgs/3.jpg").unwrap();
                let thumbnail = img.resize(400,400, FilterType::Lanczos3);
                let (x, y) = thumbnail.dimensions();
                let rgb = RgbImage::new(&thumbnail.to_bytes(), x, y, 3).unwrap();
                t.set_image(Some(rgb));
                *dnd = false;
                *released = false;
                true
            } else {
                false
            }
        }
        Event::DndLeave => {
            *dnd = false;
            *released = false;
            true
        }
        _ => false,
    }
}
```